# SharedPreferences doesn't work android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a sharedPreferences object and SharedPreferencesEdit object but doesn't save anything

```
public void getPreferences(){
      SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = sp.edit();

      spEditor.putString("us1_Name", us1_Name.getText().toString());
      spEditor.commit();
  }

  public void setPreferences(){
      SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

      us1_Name.setText(sp.getString("us1_Name", "DEFAULT"));


  }
```

---

I call this methods when onStop and onResume call, but doesn't work for me.

Comment: your setPrefrence is code of get , and get is code of set

Comment: `getPreferences()` is already a method of Activity. It's actually `Activity.getPreferences(int Mode)` but you should change the name of your custom method to clear up the possible confusion and future bugs if you change the arguments or make an overloaded version that takes an int.

Comment: Are you sure `onStop()` is actually being called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to exchange your `preference` methods from your `getPreferences()` to `setPreferences()` like

```
public void getPreferences(){
  SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  us1_Name.setText(sp.getString("us1_Name", "DEFAULT"));
 }

public void setPreferences(){
   SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = sp.edit();
   spEditor.putString("us1_Name", us1_Name.getText().toString());
   spEditor.commit();
 }
```

in your `getPreferences()` you need to get saved `preferences` value by using

```
sp.getString("us1_Name", "DEFAULT")
```

in your `setPreferences()` you need to saved `preferences` value by using

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = sp.edit();
 spEditor.putString("us1_Name", us1_Name.getText().toString());
 spEditor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing is that

1.) don't do any operations like sharedPreferance Edit / Database edit in onStop(); method

because it just call just for moment and it is only for do minor operation regarding activity

so please change it and do it in onPause();